# How to deal with VLC memory leak of simply playing & stoping with video filter on

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, vlc, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm seeing a memory leak (10M each time) when I play->stop->play->stop a local mp4 file using both libvlcsharp and the officially released  VLC media player(3.0.16) when video filter is applied.

Since I'm having multiple(around 10) VideoView displayed simultaneously in my program, OOM error occurs in like 20 play&stop operations.
I'm using c# and I've tried GC.Collect() in my program, it didn't work.
Anything I can do about this?

FYI: The video filter I've tried: ripple, sharpen, wave. And both libvlcsharp and VLC media player works fine without video filter.

Edit 1:
The vout is dx3d11 and the I'm using VLC media player on windows10.

Comment: Found a PR that might work, will update this question after trying.

https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/commit/06a7da1b97684f0b6b538fabb93bd167ab640f63

Comment: If the nightlies doesn't fix your issue, then please open a new ticket

Comment: And https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/commit/c010c528aa191d5936aa72db8874349c8320dae6

Comment: @cube45 Will update this thread and open a ticket if necessary.

Comment: @cube45 Neither of these commit works. And I tried the latest nightly (20211125-0422), it leaks memory too. I've created a new ticket https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc/-/issues/26323.

Comment: I know this is quite an old entry, but did you came across a solution to this? I have exactly the same issue when applying some cropping video filters and just playing and stopping the video.